# Using the genitive with "University of Phoenix at"

Tags: possessives

Today, I have a question regarding using apostrophes with long proper nouns such as the "University of Phoenix at Little Rock".

Should I say the following?

> This person is a graduate of the University of Phoenix at Little Rock's communications program.

Is this okay? Should I place the apostrophe somewhere else, or rephrase the sentence completely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the title of the institution is "University of Phoenix at Little Rock" then your sentence is fine, it just feels heavy because of the length of the proper name.

It might feel better written:

> This person is a graduate of the Communications Program at the
>   University of Phoenix in Little Rock

...assuming that the Communications Program is the title (proper name) of a course and not just a description